# Linked server setup by addlinkedsrvlogin

Tags: sql-server, database, linked-server

I want to copy all linked server setup from one server (SQL Server 2008 R2) to new server (SQL Server 2016) by using `sp_addlinkedsrvlogin`.

Do you have an example of code to do this? Or any better way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: you can right click generate script, but you need to type the password again.. if this is not an issue for you ?

Comment: or -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740189/migrating-multiple-linked-server-from-one-server-to-another-on-sql-server-2008-r